# Bibliography/references do not work in any capacity

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, texworks, preamble

This is my preamble, I have tried several things including running it through pdflatex (without fontspec etc.) and following documentation properly as far as I can tell (although it's clear that I'm not). I have used TeXworks and TexStudio.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\linespread{1.5}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{a title}
\author{a name}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\bibliography{essay}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
```

This is the log when I attempt to compile

```
Missing \begin{document}. \begin{thebibliography}{}
Missing \begin{document}. \begin{thebibliography}{}
Empty `thebibliography' environment
Citation `Pyne05' on page 2 undefined
Citation `loturco15' on page 2 undefined
Citation `till15' on page 2 undefined
Citation `Haguenauer05' on page 2 undefined
Citation `baptista16' on page 2 undefined
Citation `atkinson98' on page 2 undefined
Citation `atkinson98' on page 2 undefined
Citation `safrit' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Citation `comyns23' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `klavora' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Citation `comyns23' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Citation `comyns23' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `comyns23' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Citation `buckthorpe12' on page 2 undefined
Citation `comyns23' on page 2 undefined
Citation `leard' on page 2 undefined
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
There were undefined references.
```

I have no idea where to start with what's going wrong after looking at several trouble shooting article I can't find anything that's obvious enough for myself to notice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code giving the error messages? Please do not forget to add the used bib entries...

Comment: Have you compiled with `bibtex` as well as `pdflatex`? See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162)

Comment: @DaiBowen I believe that I have, I have gone to tools of texstudio and clicked on bibliography as that was a suggested fix.

Comment: Ah, `\bibliography` should go after `\begin{document}` where you want the bibliography to appear.  `\newpage` also shouldn't be in the preamble.

Comment: @DaiBowen ah the current problem is that it either isn't compiling or when it does it is just plain text without newline breaks of the .bib file.

Comment: thanks for that @DaiBowen that's fixed it, it had been telling me that it shouldn't be placed there but i guess i did it wrong